# Local markets in Istanbul

Tags: turkey, shopping, istanbul

We once happen to arrive at a Sunday market in allies while wandering around where locals sell their items from food to kitchenette and clothing. We loved the atmosphere and everything about that local market. I'd like to know more about similar bazar/local market in Istanbul with an approximate address and the day it'll be held. The one we visited was in Beyoğlu district on the European side of istanbul.

In case it does matter, we'll be there early November.

Comment: I fear this might be too broad as I think there must be tons of markets in a city as big as Istanbul. Maybe narrow this down to how to find markets?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An association for tradespeople lists all [bazaars](http://www.istanbulpazarcilarodasi.com/istanbulda-kurulan-pazarlar) in Istanbul. You may select a day and see the bazaars held that day. Nearly half of them have links to Google Maps as well. By the way, consider that the Turkish word *pazar* means both *bazaar* and *Sunday*.

There are 50-60 bazaars each day of the week, so it is hard to tell which are better for tourist attraction. I see several blogs listing the best bazaars, but they are in Turkish.

Maybe I can try to compile these lists into one list (by alphabetical order).

```
Bazaar                         Side     Open
------                         ----     ----
Bakırköy Bazaar                Europe   Sat
Beşiktaş                       Europe   Sat
Beylikdüzü Beylik Bazaar       Europe   Sat, Sun
Dolapdere Flea Market          Europe   Sun
Fatih                          Europe   Wed
Feriköy Antique Bazaar         Europe   Sun
Fındıkzade                     Europe   Fri
Kadıköy                        Asia     Tue
Ortaköy (Ulus Bazaar)          Europe   Thu
Spice Bazaar (Mısır Çarşısı)   Europe   Everyday
Sultanahmet Arasta Bazaar      Europe   Everyday
Yeşilköy                       Europe   Wed
```

Answer (score -2):

Check out the Grand Bazaar of Istanbul.

Tripadvisor:
https://www.tripadvisor.com/Attraction_Review-g293974-d294496-Reviews-Kapali_Carsi-Istanbul.html

Official Website:
http://kapalicarsi.com.tr/tr/

I am also slated to visit this in Dec.

Comment: The Grand Bazaar is the polar opposite of a "local" market.